How can an element of order p define if a $\mathbb{C}G$-module or a representation is reducible or irreducible?
I have a question as homework ,but I don't understand it intiutively at all.
Here's the question :
Let $G$ be a finite group of order $|G|=pn$,where p is a prime, and U be a subspace of $\mathbb{C}G$.If U is spanned by all the elements of order $p$ of $G$ and V is a $\mathbb{C}G$-module under the action $gh=ghg^{-1}$ ,for every $g,h \in G$ ,while the order of h is $p$, then show that if $p>2$ ,then U cannot be irreducible.
What  I've done so far :
Lets suppose that U is in fact irreducible and let $\vartheta:U\rightarrow  U$ be a projection (so $\vartheta=\vartheta^2$).From Shur's lemma we know that $\vartheta(u)=\lambda u$ but since $\vartheta$ is a projection we know in fact we need $\lambda u=\lambda^2 u$ and so $\lambda=1$ or $-i $.If we let $\vartheta(u)=\frac{1}{|G|} \sum_{g \in G} g u$ we have that equal to $u$  or $-i u$ but  that does not make sense to me at all and in reality gives me nothing to continue since i dont know what G or its elements are ,also i dont use the order of p in some way .
Any hint or help would be appreciated ,thank you for your time !

Let $S \subseteq G$ be the set of elements of order $p$. If $p > 2$, then $\dim(U) = |S| > 1$. However, the element $\sum_{x \in S} x \in U$ generates a $\mathbb{C}[G]$-submodule of dimension $1$.

But what changes if p=2 ?Why does it matter that p is a prime greater than 2 ?

@GGG If $p = 2$, then it's possible that $\dim(U) = 1$. In that case $U$ is irreducible.

Is that because in every group the number of elements of order p are a multiple of p-1  ?And if that's true the base of U would be possible to have only one element ?

Yes, a specific example would be $G = \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$.

Great. Thank you for your help !
